# How can I use sass variables with @each and with hex colors?

Tags: sass

I'm making a style guide with some color blocks. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="colorBlock _fafafa">Light Gray (#fafafa)</div>  
<div class="colorBlock _eaeaea">Gray (#eaeaea)</div>  
<div class="colorBlock _777">Meta-Gray (#777)</div>  
<div class="colorBlock _555">Gray 5 (#555)</div>  
<div class="colorBlock _444">Gray 4 (#444)</div>  
<div class="colorBlock _333">Gray 3 (#333)</div>
```

And I'd like to write some DRY-principle SASS that compiles to this CSS:

```
.colorBlock._fafafa { 
    background-color: #fafafa; 
} 
.colorBlock._eaeaea { 
    background-color: #eaeaea; 
} 
...
```

So I'm trying out lists and `@each`. Here's what I've tried:

```
$colors: fafafa eaeaea 777 555 444; 

.colorBlock { 
    @each $color in $colors { 
        &._#{$color} { 
            background-color: ##{$color}; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Which would work, but Sass doesn't like `##{$color}` and fails upon compilation. I tried `\##{$color}`, which successfully compiles, but prints `\#fafafa`. I also tried `#$color`, but that also fails on compilation (`Invalid CSS after "...kground-color: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "#$color; "`). I also tried `#{# + $color}` and other similar combinations. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Why the downvote? These are two very different issues. Since my colors are hex values without the `#` prefix, it's a unique problem. If I had semantic colors like `red`, `green`, etc, I would have no problems, but the problem is that the `##` collision causes all kinds of compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to quote it, then unquote it.  Keep in mind that these values *are not colors* when you do this and cannot be used in any color manipulation functions.

```
$colors: fafafa eaeaea 777 555 444; 

.colorBlock { 
    @each $color in $colors { 
        &._#{$color} { 
            background-color: unquote('##{$color}'); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with some string concatenation: `background-color: #{'#' + $color};`. It turns out I also had to quote colors in the list that have leading zeros: `$colors: fafafa eaeaea 777 555 444 '07d';`.